# I want to return the array index, not the array value

Tags: c++

Homework question that I can't figure out. Not even gonna lie. It's suppose to return the array index where my function finds the character it's searching for or return -1 if it doesn't find the character. Instead it returns the value stored in the arrays element. i.e. I type "This is my string" it should return 8 but instead it returns 109(ASCII code of M).

```
int search(const std::string &array, char character) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        if (i = character) {
            return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I'm taking a break from homework for the day, but any advice would be appreciated. Maybe I'll see the problem tomorrow with fresh eyes.

Comment: `(i = character)` -> `(i == character)` -> `(array[i] == character)`

Comment: Spoiler: there's another issue. Keep looking ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
int search(const std::string &array, char character) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) { 
        if (i **==**character) {
            return i;
         } 
         return -1; 
    } 
}
```

In your loop, i = character is not a comparison, it's an assignement. In c++, the comparison operator is == .

On a side note, you could replace your whole function by the function [find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

**EDIT**

What I failed to see is that your if is wrong AND your for too.

Here is a working piece of code :

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
int search(const std::string &array, char character) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        if (array[i] == character) {
            return i;
        }

    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
std::string meh = "meh";
std::cout << search(meh,'e') << std::endl;

}
```

First error, you have to compare the element of the array with character, not the counter (i).
Second error, you're returning -1 if you if failed in your for. But if the character is not the first character in the string, it will fail.

Thanks @quentin for having me take a second look.

Comment: <s>association</s> assignment. But that's only one of the issues with this code.

Comment: Thanks a bunch...I had the double equal originally, but must have changed it while I was trying anything else. The array[i] was the big thing screwing me up so thanks for the tip on that. This was the only question on my homework I couldn't figure out. Thanks again. P.S. i can't upvote your response because people downvoted my clearly noobish question otherwise I would have.

Answer (score 1):

std::string::find() returns exactly what you want:

```
std::size_t search(const std::string& array, char character)
{
    return array.find(character); // if 'character' is not found returns std::string::npos
}
```

And if you don't want to use it:

```
std::size_t search(const std::string& array, char character)
{
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<array.size(); ++i)
        if(array[i]==character) return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use that, but my teacher didn't want me to. I'm guessing because I clearly need more practice on array/loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
int search(const std::string &array, char character);
int main () {
const std::string string1 = "daidalos";
std::cout << search(string1, 'i');
return 0;
}
int search(const std::string &array, char character) {
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    if (array[i] == character) {
        return i+1;
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

Output:
`3` means 3rd place (true).However, if you want to return multiple indexes of the string, you can use an `std::pair` or `std::tupple`.

Answer (score 0):

Excatly what I was looking for.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
int search(const std::string &array, char character) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        if (array[i] == character) {
            return i;
        }

    }
    return -1;
}
```